# Why is this Community Wiki answer branded with a deadname?

Tags: bug

[Early 90's children's book about a girl who travelled back in time](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/33333/early-90s-childrens-book-about-a-girl-who-travelled-back-in-time?rq=1) has a Community Wiki name which is credited to "Richard". Clicking through reveals Valorum (who, indeed, once used that other name). Why isn't the name updated here?

Comment: [This is an _old_ bug.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47474/345161)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, that's not the correct use of the term deadname, but I can understand how that *could* happen to somebody who had changed their name for those reasons.

Comment: Are you happy now?

Comment: I am satisfied.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Then go in peace, my son, and [spread joy into the world](https://media.giphy.com/media/l0MYvuswf6Hp8jnpe/giphy.gif).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a Community Wiki post is created or edited, a copy of the primary author’s username is stored. Therefore, it won’t be changed by that user updating their name (or deleting their account).

Only an edit (even the most trivial) will update the name on these posts.

See also my [MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323637/323179) saying the same — but with screenshots!

Comment: Ooh. ***With screenshots***. How can anyone resist that kind of temptation?